# Can't fetch iOS 16 Beta Device Activity Data Application localizedDisplayName

Tags: ios, swift, ios16

I am using iOS 16 beta 3 and try to fetch all of the applications daily screen duration times. I am using the code bellow it fetches duration and bundleIdentifier but localizedDisplayName always returns nil. Does anyone facing with the same issue? Is it a beta problem? Or am I doing something wrong?

```
struct TotalActivityReport: DeviceActivityReportScene {

// Define which context your scene will represent.
let context: DeviceActivityReport.Context = .totalActivity

// Define the custom configuration and the resulting view for this report.
let content: (ActivityReport) -> TotalActivityView

func makeConfiguration(representing data: DeviceActivityResults<DeviceActivityData>) async -> ActivityReport {
    // Reformat the data into a configuration that can be used to create
    // the report's view.
    var list: [AppDeviceActivity] = []
    let totalActivityDuration = await data.flatMap { $0.activitySegments }.reduce(0, {
        $0 + $1.totalActivityDuration
    })
    for await d in data {
        for await a in d.activitySegments{
            for await c in a.categories {
                for await ap in c.applications {
                    let appName = (ap.application.localizedDisplayName ?? "nil")
                    let bundle = (ap.application.bundleIdentifier ?? "nil")
                    let duration = (ap.totalActivityDuration)
                    let app = AppDeviceActivity(id: bundle, displayName: appName, duration: duration)
                    list.append(app)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    return ActivityReport(totalDuration: totalActivityDuration, apps: list)
}}
```

Comment: did you find anything related to this?

Comment: Yes before the launch of iOS 16 Apple fixed the issue.

Comment: could you please share your demo project or git repository with me..i am having trouble implementing this ?

Comment: Ok I will create a tutorial for this and let you know when published.

Comment: Okay Thanks, Desperately waiting!

Comment: If you can share demo, that will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sorry for delay I was busy. I couldn't create a tutorial so I have uploaded the demo project to Github: https://github.com/ninja342/Screen-Time. I hope it helps.

Comment: @TarıkYılıkoğlu Thank you so much for sharing your project. I've tested it and confirmed it's working. However, it seems like Apple completely blocked getting the activity information from the report. I've added `print` to check activity information, but it does not work. :'(

Comment: here some code with detail and data - https://kushwaha03.medium.com/the-screen-time-api-and-whats-new-in-screen-time-api-50a1404c130e

Comment: Is there any way to get the screen duration of apps for specific time range ?

I tried by changing the segment in the filter like this `segment: .daily(during: timeRange)`. But still giving duration for full day.